# permission denied BASH

Tags: bash, permissions, scripts

I want to run a shell script called `start.sh` on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server.  So I type `./start.sh` and it wont run.  I'm new, just putting that out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply exec permission to the file.  You can do this with:

```
$ chmod +x start.sh
```

Comment: I thought the name was familiar.   It's a pleasure!